# In PHP, is too many assignments are considered bad? If so why?

Tags: php

Netbeans seems to suggest too many assignments is quite bad and should be changed.

i.e.

```
$foo = ' bar ';
$foo = trim($foo);
```

Should better coded as

```
$foo = ' bar ';
$trimmed_foo = trim($foo);
```

Is this acceptable? If so why? I know I can switch this particular hint type off in setting, but just checking if someone spotted anything for this.

Comment: This is an interesting question. I image that it really doesn't matter but the PHP engine has surprised me before.

Comment: Thanks for not accepting answers that do not answering.

Answer (score 7):

Ths is a new warning, circa mid 2012.

Since you used the trim example I'm guessing that you have read this https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/several_new_hints, which tries to explain the warning.  My take on this warning is that it's trying to warn you about accidental reuse of a variable. As such it is very handy.  In the trim case you give it seems a bit heavy handed. If the reassignment is on he following line, it's probably not accidental.

Comment: Correct Peter, I did read the page you quoted, it does not exactly tell you why it's bad though. Stop it from accidentally happening in a good reason to keep it switched on.

Answer (score 5):

Ideally the variable name should describe the contents. If you are repeatedly assigning to the same variable, it suggests that the variables contents are not well defined.

Additionally, if your code has something like this:

```
$foo = ' bar ';
// some code, mybe 100 lines of it
// now do something with $foo
```

What happens if you update the code to add `$foo = trim($foo);` up above? You break the code below.

Answer (score 5):

Those variants make no difference. If anything the first is better because it avoids cluttering the scope with variables.

I think what the warning really means is that you should try to do

```
$foo = trim(' bar ');
```

directly (or whatever $foo is really being set to in the first place), instead of storing it in a temporary. Of course, this isn't always possible.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like this hint, you can simply deactivate it in Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Hints -> PHP -> Immutable Variables

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, first way is ok for more performance comparing second.

On the other hand, second approach can be more helpful if you need more descriptive variables. Also this may help more if multiple persons are working on same project.